# ListView doesn't show all ListItems

Tags: javascript, listview, titanium, titanium-alloy

In a Titanium Alloy mobile app project:

```
var apptList = Ti.UI.createListView();
var calendar = Ti.UI.createListSection({ headerTitle: 'Appointments'});
var appts = [];
var apptsData = [];
```

.....

```
//format: null, Startdate, Enddate, Location, AppoinmentID (repeats)
apptsData = parseDates(this.responseText);
Ti.API.info(apptsData.toString());
```

My parseDates function returns these values as an array, below I have the toString shown. (It is OK that they aren't all dates)

```
,2013-09-30T00:00:00Z,2013-09-30T00:13:00Z,Dayton Ohio,1,,2015-10-05T00:00:00Z,2015-10-30T00:13:00Z,New York,2,,1992-10-07T00:00:00Z,1992-10-07T00:13:00Z,Demoines,3,,2013-09-30T00:00:00Z,2013-09-30T00:13:00Z,Bellbrook Ohio,4,
```

For whatever reason I *cannot* get those values to show in my ListView. I can't even access any part of the array beyond those values.

In addition incrementing by certain values crashes my app (no error message) and some do not (e.g. i += 5 crashes, i +=6 does not) as if I'm accessing data that isn't there or some other memory issue.

```
         for(var i = 0; i <= 20; i += 5){
            //skips null
            Ti.API.info(apptsData[i + 1]);
            appts.push({properties: {title: apptsData[i + 1]}});    //Start Date
            Ti.API.info(apptsData[i + 2]);
            appts.push({properties: {title: apptsData[i + 2]}});    //End Date
            Ti.API.info(apptsData[i + 3]);
            appts.push({properties: {title: apptsData[i + 3]}});    //Location

         }
```

The first loop will push & print (the same values are displayed in my ListView):

```
[INFO] :   2013-09-30T00:00:00Z
[INFO] :   2013-09-30T00:13:00Z
[INFO] :   Dayton Ohio
```

But after that I just get nulls.

```
        Ti.API.info("length: " + apptsData.length);
```

Length returns 6 while it should be higher.

Below I'm trying to add the listview/section to my window

```
        var calendar = Ti.UI.createListSection({ items: appts });
        apptList.sections = [calendar];
        $.calendarWindow.add(apptList);
```

Comment: Step through the application using the debugger, keep checking the apptsData value as you step through it.  I know some like to depend on Ti.API.info for debugging.  There probably isn't enough source code here to determine the problem.  I know on some projects it is difficult to give just the right amount of code, but when it is all chopped up like this, you can't really help determine where it went wrong.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do that. For whatever reason my debugger is screwed up (does not display variable values and doesn't stop at breakpoints). But I suppose that is an entirely different issue.

If I fix it and solve my problem I'll be sure to post an update.

Answer (score 0):

If `apptsData.length` (right after where it comes back from `parseDates()`) gives `6` instead of the number you expect, then clearly there's something wrong with `this.responseText` or `parseDates()` and the issue is not related to the ListView.

Use `console.info(JSON.stringify(apptsData, null, ' '))` to get a better view of the array, or like Martin says, step through and inspect the value.

Answer (score 0):

OK the solution is a little more dumb than I would like.

Essentially what was happening in my parseDates function I was recursively adding arrays together to get all the info I needed. Unfortunately I was using **array.push(otherarray)** instead of **array.concat(otherarray)**

I doubt this answer will help anyone else out but if you ever have similar symptoms as I had above be sure to look at this solution.